# How do I use AutoMapper with eager-loading and collections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This statement returns a list of people and their addresses and phone numbers.

```
var listOfPeople = db.People.AsQueryable();
```

Now, I'd like to use AutoMapper to map the results of the above LINQ statement to a view model. The view model was created mainly to prevent some properties from being returned to the client / user.

How do I get AutoMapper to map the results, `listOfPeople`, to a view model composed of the base object, `Person`, and `ICollections` of `Addresses` and `PhoneNunmbers`? I don't have a problem mapping a single person to a single vm. I think I'm getting hung up on mapping a collection, `listOfPeople`, that contains a couple of collections within.

I'm using `ASP.NET Web API 4`, not MVC 4.

Here is the view model

```
public class BasicApiViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, there is no need to separately configure collection mappings, you just need to define mapping between classes (as you've already done), and collections will be handled automatically

> AutoMapper only requires configuration of element types, not of any
>   array or list type that might be used. For example, we might have a
>   simple source and destination type:

```
public class Source
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

> All the basic generic collection types are supported:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

var sources = new[]
    {
        new Source { Value = 5 },
        new Source { Value = 6 },
        new Source { Value = 7 }
    };

IEnumerable<Destination> ienumerableDest = Mapper.Map<Source[], IEnumerable<Destination>>(sources); 
ICollection<Destination> icollectionDest = Mapper.Map<Source[], ICollection<Destination>>(sources); 
IList<Destination> ilistDest = Mapper.Map<Source[], IList<Destination>>(sources);    
List<Destination> listDest = Mapper.Map<Source[], List<Destination>>(sources); 
Destination[] arrayDest = Mapper.Map<Source[], Destination[]>(sources);
```

[Lists and arrays](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays)

Comment: I also needed to map the classes for the collections for Phone numbers and Addresses. Then, everything worked as expected. Thanks!